# How to install additional driver to GDAL installed with apt-get

Tags: gdal, geojson, ubuntu, apt-get

I have installed [GDAL 2.2.3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/gdal) on Ubuntu 18.04 using apt-get. I'd like to add the [GeoJSONSeq driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojsonseq.html#vector-geojsonseq).

How can this be done?

Comment: As far as I know you have to upgrade gdal to version 2.4 - the version that has geojsonseq built into it.  If it's not available on apt, you'll probably have to build it yourself from source

Comment: Steve, you could create a separate (non apt/deb) more recent gdal install with a conda environment. Install miniconda, `conda create -c conda-forge -n mynewgdalenv 'gdal>=2.4' python any_other_package_you_need`

Comment: I also highly recommend using conda.  It's a lot easier to work with because it generally takes care of dependencies for each package (it definitely does this for gdal)

Comment: Sounds promising, either of you want to write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be to use a Personal Package Archive (PPA). The [NextGIS ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nextgis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) currently has GDAL 2.4.0 for xenial, trusty and bionic ubuntu.

The [ubuntugis stable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) also has 2.4.0 for bionic currently (January 2020).

To upgrade your GDAL to 2.4.0 using the NextGIS PPA, it should look something like this:

```
apt-get install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:nextgis/ppa
apt -y update
apt -y upgrade gdal-bin
```